# ASP.NET Web Page is Broken When ABCPDF component is Loaded (dump files attached here)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, abcpdf

I am using ABCPDF to convert HTML to PDF.  The version is 7.0.4.2.  With the same codes, it works fine in my development server (Windows 7) and Production Server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard).  However when I deploy the ASP.NET application to a bland new server (same Window version as the working production server).  The page is broken when the ABCPDF component is loaded.  I managed to get the dump files.  There are two folders are created in the dump directory.  One folder called default.  The ABCPDF has been bound correctly there; another folder called NativeImage.  The component image can not be found.  Here are the dump files.  Any one can see what is wrong here.  Thanks,

1. Dump file in Default folder -

   *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/12/2012 @ 10:52:45 PM) ***

   The operation was successful.
   Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

   Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
   Running under executable  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
   --- A detailed error log follows.

   === Pre-bind state information ===
   LOG: User = Unknown
   LOG: DisplayName = ABCpdf, Version=7.0.4.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7a0b3f5184f2169
    (Fully-specified)
   LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/WebIS_80/
   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = E:\WebIS_80\bin
   LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\266bb899
   LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\266bb899
   LOG: AppName = 7a8839af

   ## Calling assembly : ISEP.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

   LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
   LOG: Using application configuration file: E:\WebIS_80\web.config
   LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config
   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
   LOG: Post-policy reference: ABCpdf, Version=7.0.4.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7a0b3f5184f2169
   LOG: Found assembly by looking in the GAC.
   LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ABCpdf\7.0.4.2__a7a0b3f5184f2169\ABCpdf.dll.
   LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
2. Dump file in NativeImage folder -

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/12/2012 @ 10:52:50 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = Unknown
LOG: DisplayName = ABCpdf, Version=7.0.4.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7a0b3f5184f2169
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/WebIS_80/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = E:\WebIS_80\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\266bb899
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\266bb899
LOG: AppName = 7a8839af

## Calling assembly : ISEP.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

LOG: Start binding of native image ABCpdf, Version=7.0.4.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7a0b3f5184f2169.
WRN: No matching native image found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their version 7 does not work with IE9. Internally IE components are called from their DLL.  After downgraded to IE8 in server, it works now

Answer (score 0):

Does ABCPDF has a non-managed library that needs to be installed?  Make sure you've run the installer for ABCPDF on the new server.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, The installer has been downloaded from http://www.websupergoo.com/download.htm and run.  No sure what is the non-managed library.  Is it abcpdfce7.dll?  I could not find it in any folder after run the installer.  I could not see it in my machine either.  But it works there.

Comment: After a second look, AbcPdfCE7.dll is in C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32.  No sure is there any other non-managed library.